# Get Virtuemart Category from Product table (Joomla / Virtuemart)

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

Trying to find out what binds vm_product and vm_category together in a typical Joomla / Virtuemart installation.

Idea is to push the category information in the $product_rows array of administrator > components > com_virtuemart > html > basket.php and what is echoed at basket_b2c.html.php. But for that I need to know the associations.

New to Joomla.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it. The association table is : vm_product_category_xref